# How to export the users homedir path to a variable and safe it to accsess in root shell

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I'd like to write a basch script that should install some files in tan users home dir and set up some packages.

Because the script will be opend with sudo I need to export the users homedir path into a variable and save it before I call a second script with sudo the second script should use the variable instead of the full path to the users home dir.

I'm extreamly new to bash and this seems to be a challenge to me,

I looked at the suggestions above but nothing seems to fit to my needs,

Thank you for investigation

Comment: Why do you want to use a user's home directory from a script running as root?  Usually if the user's directory is to be modified, the script doing it should run as that user.

Comment: I need to put some files for the user there after a clean install. so i have to know the name of the users directory although the user choose it while the installation.

Comment: A better approach would be to modify the userhome skeleton before user creation.

Answer (score 1):

Get a user's homedirectory like this:

```
homedir=$(getent passwd $username | cut -d: -f6)
```

Comment: getent isn't available on OSX.

Answer (score 0):

or just "~user", where user is the login name of the user whose home dir you want